# How to dynamic load the library with same name but in different directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, libraries, dlopen

I have to dynamic load .so in Linux, but I find it is difficult to deal with the same name libraries.
I have 2 libtest.so in different directories and they are depend on other different libraries.
My program read config file to decide to load which libtest.so. For example:

```
/usr/kyle/v1/libtest.so
/usr/kyle/v2/libtest.so
```

They are all not registered in ldconfig. 
So how can I load different version of libtest.so using dlopen? I hope that they will not be conflict with each other, because they may be depend on same or different other libraries. It seems that change LD_LIBRARY_PATH using putenv/setenv in my program does not work.

Comment: How are you calling `dlopen`?

Comment: Just dlopen("libtest.so"...). Full path does not work also. From other posts, I know that I can not change LD_LIBRARY_PATH in my process.

Comment: Full path only works if libtest.so does not depend on any other libraries.

Comment: If it depends on other libraries that exist in the same directory and might also collide with different versions in other /usr/kyle/*/ directories, then you can use rpath to specify the location, while linking libtest.so.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Glibc provide [dlmopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) for this:

```
h = dlmopen(LM_ID_NEWLM, "path/to/some/version/of/libtest.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

Comment: Note: it might not be necessary/desirable to use RTLD_LAZY.  This also doesn't address the path issue, for the library dependencies, that kyle mentions in the above comments.

Comment: @DroidCoder Thanks, I updated the path. As for `RTLD_LAZY`, I simply took the most prevalent setting.