# How to dynamically load a library which depends on other libraries having same name in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

My application loads a library which requires other dependent library that too requires other dependent library to load.

Basically it's a dependency with three levels-

1. My library(say M) which requires D1 to be loaded.
2. Dependent library(say D1) which requires D2 to be loaded.
3. Dependent library(say D2).

This is how dependency of libraries looks

```
M.so --> D1.so, D2.so
D1.so --> D2.so
```

I have two different versions(say version1 and version2) of D1 and D2 but they both share the same name. I need to keep both the versions for my application due to some unavoidable reasons. Now, my question is how can I make sure that correct version of libraries get loaded ?

I tried to think of solutions but unfortunately couldn't get one working.

```
TRY1:
```

I have a control over M.so so I thought of renaming depending libraries to D1_1.so & D2_1.so for version1 and D1_2.so & D2_2.so for version2 and created two versions of my library M1.so and M2.so.

This is how dependency of library looks now

```
M1.so --> D1_1.so,D2_1.so
D1_1.so --> D2.so

M2.so --> D1_2.so, D2_2.so
D1_2.so --> D2.so
```

But above solution does not work because both D1_1.so and D1_2.so are still looking for D2.so and I don't have a control there. I want version1 of D2.so to be loaded in first scenario and version2 of D2.so to be loaded in 2nd scenario.

```
TRY2:
```

I thought of creating two folders, one for version1 related libs and one for version2 related libs and provide absolute path of M.so in `dlopen` but that too does not work because it does not search dependent libs in path provided.

```
folder1--> M.so, D1.so, D2.so (version1)
folder2--> M.so, D1.so, D2.so (version2)
```

dlopen(./folder1/M.so) does not load M.so until LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set and if I set it to folder one, it will always load version1 of library!!! If I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to both the folders then it's not predictable which version will be loaded. Also, In my application, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set at the time of application start up.

I have seen similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525016/how-to-dynamic-load-the-library-with-same-name-but-in-different-directory-in-lin) but with no solution. Could anyone please help me to find a possible solution for my scenario?

Comment: did you try soft (symbolic) links?  (to end up with multiple names to same file).

Comment: Why is your binary setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH - that's a really bad idea for exactly this reason

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN, Yes I tried creating symlinks but that is failing for the same reason. Let's say I created sym1 and sym2 both pointing to D2.so, it still looks for D2.so and not symlinks sym1 & sym2. Basically sym1 & sym2 don't help to get to D2.so while loading.

Comment: @UKMonkey, this use-case is just a part of huge application. There are other dependent libraries which are required to be dynamically loaded in other component of application at run time. Is there any other way it can find dependent libraries without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH ?

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367600/what-is-the-order-that-linuxs-dynamic-linker-searches-paths-in

Comment: @UKMonkey, My application is a complete package which has all the dependent libraries contained in it. It should work out of the box and that is the reason all the dependent libraries are shipped with the application.(It should essentially search libraries in my application folder only).

Comment: "It should work out of the box" - no reason to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  The user for example might have moved some other shared libs that you also depend on and now it's going to break.  What you really should be asking is how to package your application so that your binary can work out the box; which is very different to this!

Comment: I ship all the dependent libraries with the application. when application starts, it sets required environment variables only for that process. User is not allowed to change the folders created by application installation. My application works out of the box but now I have a requirement to add latest version of the dependent library(keeping the old one as well because some scenarios need old one) only for one component. Issue is both old and new dependent libraries have same name and I want to know how to make sure that it loads old version when old is required and new version when new one is.